# Why am I getting an IllegalStateException trying to load resource by related path to .fxml file using TornadoFX?

Tags: kotlin, fxml, illegalstateexception, tornadofx

I am working on UI using TornadoFX with Kotlin. So I'm trying to load the start page of my app, here's a code for main-function:

```
fun main() {
    launch<UIApp>()
}
```

app()-inheriting class:

```
class UIApp: App(AuthorizationView::class)
```

and view()-inheriting class:

```
class AuthorizationView: View() {

    override val root: AnchorPane by fxml("./src/main/resources/authorizationView.fxml")

}
```

The directory tree is the following:
[directory tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7aGy.png)

When I run the main fun I get this trace:

```
SEVERE: Uncaught error
java.lang.IllegalStateException: component.javaClass.getResource(resource) must not be null
    at tornadofx.ResourceLookup.url(Component.kt:1304)
    at tornadofx.FX$Companion$fxmlLocator$1.invoke(FX.kt:114)
    at tornadofx.FX$Companion$fxmlLocator$1.invoke(FX.kt:88)
    at tornadofx.UIComponent.loadFXML(Component.kt:1119)
    at tornadofx.UIComponent$fxml$1.<init>(Component.kt:1113)
    at tornadofx.UIComponent.fxml(Component.kt:1112)
    at tornadofx.UIComponent.fxml$default(Component.kt:1112)
    at com.lowlevel.librarysheet.view.AuthorizationView.<init>(AuthorizationView.kt:8)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at tornadofx.FXKt.find(FX.kt:434)
    at tornadofx.FXKt.find$default(FX.kt:423)
    at tornadofx.App.start(App.kt:83)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$8(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$7(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$5(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$6(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$4(WinApplication.java:185)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Exception in Application stop method
янв 06, 2022 5:06:35 PM tornadofx.DefaultErrorHandler uncaughtException
SEVERE: Uncaught error
java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application stop method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:922)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$1(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: component.javaClass.getResource(resource) must not be null
    at tornadofx.ResourceLookup.url(Component.kt:1304)
    at tornadofx.FX$Companion$fxmlLocator$1.invoke(FX.kt:114)
    at tornadofx.FX$Companion$fxmlLocator$1.invoke(FX.kt:88)
    at tornadofx.UIComponent.loadFXML(Component.kt:1119)
    at tornadofx.UIComponent$fxml$1.<init>(Component.kt:1113)
    at tornadofx.UIComponent.fxml(Component.kt:1112)
    at tornadofx.UIComponent.fxml$default(Component.kt:1112)
    at com.lowlevel.librarysheet.view.AuthorizationView.<init>(AuthorizationView.kt:8)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at tornadofx.FXKt.find(FX.kt:434)
    at tornadofx.FXKt.find$default(FX.kt:423)
    at tornadofx.App.stop(App.kt:139)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:882)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$7(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$5(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$6(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$4(WinApplication.java:185)
    ... 1 more
```

I've tried different ways of setting path to .fxml view including inserting an absolute path but I still get this exception.

Comment: `component.javaClass.getResource(resource) must not be null` this might be a clue.

Comment: @Alex.T I understand this, but all the paths (correct ones) I've tried lead to this trace